# is there a way to load drawable to Imageview as soon as item shown on listview

Tags: android, image, listview, scroll, out-of-memory

Scroll **grid view** with plenty amount of local Images make my app crashes in devices have small amount of RAM with message `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` or at-least in good performance devices it's **scroll very Barely** and with lag. I goggled for solution and find some good solutions are exist for remote Images like: Universal-Image-Loader that  loading images from web and cashes them and manage scrolling. but I couldn't use that on my case.

this is my adapter that load images:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StructureCase> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater           = null;
    public Context         context;
    public Class           distinationActivity = null;



    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<StructureCase> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
       // mInflater = (LayoutInflater)G.currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {


        public ImageView gem_img   = null;
        public TextView  gem_name   = null;      


    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final View v;

        final StructureCase item = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {


            convertView = this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_grid_list,  null);
            //mInflater = (LayoutInflater)G.currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_grid_list, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


            viewHolder.gem_img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_mygrid_list);
            viewHolder.gem_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_mygrid_list);           
            viewHolder.gem_name.setTypeface(G.typeFacePrs);



        } else {
           viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }




        viewHolder.gem_name.setText(item.g_name);


        int id = G.currentActivity.getResources().getIdentifier(item.g_image+"_tmb", "drawable", G.currentActivity.getPackageName());


        if(id != 0){
            Drawable drawable = G.currentActivity.getResources().getDrawable(id);
            viewHolder.gem_img.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }else{
            viewHolder.gem_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gem1);

        }


        viewHolder.gem_img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(G.currentActivity, GemDetaileActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", item.g_ID);
                i.putExtra("content", item.g_text);
                i.putExtra("name", item.g_name);
                i.putExtra("name_en", item.g_name_en);
                i.putExtra("image", item.g_image);
                i.putExtra("image_count", item.g_image_count);
                i.putExtra("hadis", item.g_hadis);
                i.putExtra("good_for", item.g_good_for);
                G.currentActivity.startActivity(i);
                G.currentActivity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_left_2_right, R.anim.out_left_2_right);

            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

I think my problem is for **pre-Loading all Images** and if there is a way to load Drawable to Image view as soon as show it's item in scroll, my problem will solve.

Comment: `List<StructureCase> objects`. You are doing nothing with `objects`. `getItem(position);`. You omitted the code for getItem(). Please add. `Drawable drawable = G.currentActivity.getResources().getDrawable(id);
            viewHolder.gem_img.setImageDrawable(drawable);` change that to one statement `viewHolder.gem_img.setImageResource(id);`.

Comment: Further: if your app crashes you will have an error report in the logcat which tells you the cause. Please tell and post relevant part from logcat.

Comment: thanks. but nothings change in preload. all images loads in beginning and still scroll crashes the app. also I used  StructureCase item = getItem(position); to get for Example image name from my object in: item.g_image

Comment: Please react to the point on all my comments and suggestions. What did you do with them?

Comment: @greenapps as i told you in third comment nothing changes with your advice and app still scroll barely. as I aksed in question I wanna use a solution that load image to ImageView on demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem with help of a friend with Picasso. it's a 
A powerful image downloading and caching library for Android. I know about that but I didn't know It also can use on local resources.

you must download last jar file and add it to your project dependencies. add in build gradle like this:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.2'
```

and then you can use it in these ways:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```

here is the link of [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).